# Having a flex project, how to compile it with mxmlc (not using flashBuilder gui)?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, compiler-construction, command-line, project

So I hava a [usual flex project](http://code.google.com/p/cloudobserver/source/browse/?r=972#svn/trunk/CloudObserverAdvancedPlayer) folder with `.actionScriptProperties`  `.flexProperties`  `.project` files in it and `src`, `libs`, `html-template` dirs. All my libs are in libs folder and my project is generally theme independent (I use costume theam). Jenerally it is simple live TCP stream video player - only default mx components. I want to have some  kind of bat/sh script file for compiling my project from command terminal/cmd in realise mode into specific directory. How to do such thing?

Is there anything like

```
mxmlc compileDefaultApplication fromProject=pathToProject toRealiseDir=pathToRealiseDir
```

?

Comment: Along with the answer below you may want to look into HFCD (hellfire compiler daemon, which lives outside the IDE process and will run the compilations for you)

Comment: Another alternative is "mavenizing" the project that is setting up the directory structure and a pom.xml file so that maven can run the build, you can use the flexmojos:flexbuilder plugin to create project properties for import into eclipse among other plugins for other IDEs and can choose to compile from the command line with a simple "mvn clean install".  This is more of a change in process though and would require some consideration for it's advantages/drawbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_13.html

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_09.html#138195

```
mxmlc MyApp.mxml load-config my-app-config.xml output /pathToRelease
```

In order to get the config in Flex/Flash builder you can go to the project properties and add this to the compiler arguments:

> ```
>  -dump-config C:\Users\shusain\Desktop\slotConfig.xml
> ```

with an appropriate path

Comment: grate!) Now My Next question - how to create variables in it? (I need such thing because it generates absolute paths while I want to make it more flexable=)

Comment: And is it possible to put it into specific location not into bin with swf but into the same folder where .project is?

Comment: Hi Blender (BTW love the program if that's what you're name refers to, lots of awesome for free).  Sorry got myself into a project for the moment, and I don't know off hand, as we use maven here for the most part, but I'll try to come back to this today after hours and let you know if I find a way to make these other things happen.

Comment: I can answer this right quick -- this trick works great for multi-environment conditional compiler blocks if you're pushing out to different environments etc.: -define+=NAMESPACE_NAME::var_name,value.  Darron Shall did some of this stuff in a json parser -- do a google search for "JSON_TOKEN::COMMA,0" for specific examples.